# TextView not appearing in embedded LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

I am creating a simple tasklist app, and I want to programmatically add a TextView to an embedded LinearLayout. However, it is not showing up for some reason.

I try to add the TextView in MainActivity (irrelevant code removed).

```java
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        processExtraData();
    }
private void processExtraData(){
        Integer hours = 4;
        Integer minutes = 35;
        Integer seconds = 0;
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlayout);
        TextView txt1 = new TextView(this);
        final float scale = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int pixels = (int) (64 * scale + 0.5f);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, pixels, 1f);
        txt1.setLayoutParams(params);                        txt1.setText(hours.toString()+":"+minutes.toString()+":"+seconds.toString());
        linearLayout.addView(txt1);
}
```

The embedded LinearLayout is declared in activity_main:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Super Reminder App!"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/taskAdd"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3.5"
            android:hint="New Task" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:text="Add Task" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="12.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/tasks"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linlayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
    android:id="@+id/clearButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="Clear All" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have already tested and made sure that onNewIntent and processExtraData are called. No errors are thrown either. Could this be a GUI issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you've got the width and height mixed up for the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. That `TextView` is going into a vertical `LinearLayout`, but you've set the width at `0`.

Comment: That helped fix my problem. Thank you again.